# Klarna Payment Api

Tags: php, klarna

I am trying to integrate the Klarna payment API into my project. But when I making API request getting this in response Caught exception: Unexpected response HTTP status 401. Excepted HTTP status should be in 2xx range

Comment: HTTP Status Code 401: The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

Answer (score 0):

TO every api calls you must add the `Authorization: Basic base64(login:password)` header.

The credentials can be generated on the settings at [this playground URL](https://playground.eu.portal.klarna.com/settings/credentials/api) and you can have 5 login per merchant.